# Why does command substitution work in these ways?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

In my .bashrc file I have the following:

```
export USER_HOME1='/home/$(id -nu)/' 
export USER_HOME2='/home/'$(id -nu)'/'
export USER_HOME3="/home/$(id -nu)/"
export USER_HOME4="/home/\$(id -nu)/"
```

Command substitution only works for USER_HOME2 and USER_HOME3. How does it work for USER_HOME2?

Within single quotes, the '$' is treated as a literal character instead of taking on any special meaning.
Within double quotes, certain characters take on special meaning and require escaping if we need to use them literally.
This would explain why command substitution works in USER_HOME3 but not in USER_HOME1 and USER_HOME4.

How does USER_HOME2 work?
How does the shell know how to pair up the single quotes?
Does it effectively concatenate three strings: '/home/', the output of $(id -nu), and '/'?
In which case, we can rewrite USER_HOME2 as

```
export USER_HOME2=/home/$(id -nu)/
```

Comment: `How does the shell know how to pair up the single quotes?` Like literally _pairs_ them? `'/home/'` that's one pair, `'/'` that's another pair.

Comment: The shell expands everything then applies word splitting based on spaces. If there are no spaces in your expanded string, or there are but it's quoted, it doesn't get split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does USER_HOME2 work? How does the shell know how to pair up the single quotes? Does it effectively concatenate three strings: '/home/', the output of $(id -nu), and '/'? In which case, we can rewrite USER_HOME2 as

Yes, that's exactly what's happening. The following strings are all identical from the viewpoint of the shell:

- `abc`
- `'abc'`
- `"abc"`
- `'a'b'c'`
- `"a"b"c"`
- `''abc''`
- `'ab''c'`
- `'ab'"c"`

Command substitution must be double quoted, otherwise glob expansion will be applied to the result (unless when it appears on the right hand side of the parameter assignment; in that case no further expansions will be applied)